# About the internal design of "ThreadLocal"

Tags: java, thread-safety, thread-local

I just researched the source code of Java **ThreadLocal**，I have two questions, hope you can help me！

First，why not just use **one** `Map` to store all values, instead of binding the map to a thread? Like this:

```
public class ThreadLocal<T> {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Thread, T> threadAndVal = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 

    // get value from threadAndVal.... put value to threadAndVal
}
```

And in method **set(T value)**, I didn't see any synchronization strategy. Is this thread-safe?

```
    public void set(T value) {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
        if (map != null)
            map.set(this, value);
        else
            createMap(t, value);  // ⬅️Why createMap is thread safe？
    }
```

Thank you for your help！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why not use a `ConcurrentHashMap`?**

The primary reason is performance. Using a thread-safe map is significantly slower than using a custom map without thread-safety.

The secondary reason is that a `Map<Thread,T>` would keep a reference to both the thread and value for as long as the `ThreadLocal` exists, and they are often used as statics.

A fun third reason is that I can create a `Thread` with overridden `equals` and `hashCode` that behaves naughtily.

**Is `ThreadLocal.set` thread-safe?**

It doesn't need to be. The first line is:

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
```

Everything else is done on the `Thread` `t`. All of these operation can only be done from that exact thread.